# Getting an Exception when Trying to post Data to server C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

I am using C#, .net micro framework 4.3. I am trying to post  maek empty post to server but I am always getting the exception :

> Program Started POST to
>   :http://api.lyncagent.com/sendim?dnmf=yes&sender=xxxx&recipient=yyyy&message=ferastanan&priority=Normal&subject=NetMF
>   POST complete. The thread '' (0x3) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0).
>       #### Exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException - CLR_E_FAIL (7) ####
>       #### Message: 
>       #### Microsoft.SPOT.Net.SocketNative::getaddrinfo [IP: 0000] ####
>       #### System.Net.Dns::GetHostEntry [IP: 0008] ####
>       #### System.Net.HttpWebRequest::EstablishConnection [IP: 00e1] ####
>       #### System.Net.HttpWebRequest::SubmitRequest [IP: 0019] ####
>       #### System.Net.HttpWebRequest::GetResponse [IP: 000c] ####
>       #### Gadgeteer.Networking.HttpRequest::HandleRequestSync [IP: 01a8] ####
>       #### SocketException ErrorCode = 10060
>       #### SocketException ErrorCode = 10060 A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.SPOT.Net.dll
>       #### SocketException ErrorCode = 10060
>       #### SocketException ErrorCode = 10060
>       #### Exception System.Net.WebException - 0x00000000 (7) ####
>       #### Message: host not available
>       #### System.Net.HttpWebRequest::EstablishConnection [IP: 00f1] ####
>       #### System.Net.HttpWebRequest::SubmitRequest [IP: 0019] ####
>       #### System.Net.HttpWebRequest::GetResponse [IP: 000c] ####
>       #### Gadgeteer.Networking.HttpRequest::HandleRequestSync [IP: 01a8] #### A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException'
>   occurred in System.Http.dll
>       #### Exception System.Net.WebException - 0x00000000 (7) ####
>       #### Message: 
>       #### System.Net.HttpWebRequest::GetResponse [IP: 00d3] ####
>       #### Gadgeteer.Networking.HttpRequest::HandleRequestSync [IP: 01a8] #### A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException'
>   occurred in System.Http.dll
>
> An exception occured while connecting to the Internet. Please, make
>   sure that a valid URL is used and a network connection is up.

here is the code:

```
string url = "http://api.lyncagent.com/sendim?dnmf=yes&sender=xxxx&recipient=yyyy&message=" + "ferastanan" + "&priority=Normal&subject=NetMF";
        Debug.Print("POST to :" + url);
        POSTContent emptyPost = new POSTContent();
        var req = HttpHelper.CreateHttpPostRequest(url, emptyPost, "text/plain");


        req.ResponseReceived += new HttpRequest.ResponseHandler(req_ResponseReceived);
        req.SendRequest();
        Debug.Print("POST complete.");
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834780/c-sharp-tcp-socket-error-10060)